# Evaluating an expected value in Jeffrey's prior for binomial distribution

Tags: probability, bayesian

The material I'm reading derives Jeffrey's prior (or rather, the Fisher information for the Jeffrey's) for single-parameter binomial distribution in a manner quite similar to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information#Single-parameter_Bernoulli_experiment).

I could work out the steps until (following Wikipedia's notation, $A$ is number of successes, $B$ failures, $A+B$ total number of trials)

$$E [\frac{A}{\theta^2} + \frac{B}{(1-\theta)^2}] \\
= \frac{E[A]}{\theta^2} + \frac{E[B]}{(1-\theta)^2}
$$

Maybe my background in probability calculus is just lacking, but I'm not exactly sure about the justification for this step. $E[\frac{A}{\theta^2}] + E[\frac{B}{(1-\theta)^2}]$ follows from the linearity properties of expected value, but the next step? Are we treating $\frac{1}{\theta^2}, \frac{1}{(1-\theta)^2}$ as constants?

Comment: Yes - at this stage of the argument, the parameter $\theta$ (the probability of success) and any functions of $\theta$ are constant, while $A$ and $B$ are random variables

Comment: Thank you; re-reading the Wikipedia article more carefully, it actually writes the expected values as $E[\dots \mid \theta]$; I guess that makes it explicit. (I wonder why I didn't thought about that.)

Comment: To see how this leads to a specific beta prior in the binomial case, google 'Jeffreys prior binomial' and look at Berkeley and Harvard links. BTW, its _Jeffreys_ not _Jeffrey's._